# How to return a string expression for order_by args in django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I want to do this in the `views` of a Django project:

```
order_by_query = request.query_params.get("order_by", "")
order_by_expression = compile_ob(order_by_query)
qs = SomeModel.objects.all().order_by(order_by_expression)
```

I expect the order_by_query to be a string like `"field1,-field2"`.

So I will write a function like:

```
def compile_ob(expression: str) -> ??:
```

My questions are:

1. what should I write inside the `compile_ob` function?
2. what should I return as type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need a function to do this. Here is an example:

```
SomeModel.objects.all().order_by(*order_by_query.split(","))
```

or you can return a list from `compile_ob` function and use it with a starred expression.

```
from typing import List
def compile_ob(expression: str) -> List[str]:
    return expression.split(",")

# somewhere in views.py
order_by_query = request.query_params.get("order_by", 'display_order')
order_by_expression = compile_ob(order_by_query)
SomeModel.objects.all().order_by(*order_by_expression)
```

Comment: i didn't test but i assume is right. I might rescind the answer if things don't work. Thank you ‍♂️

Comment: OK it works but i needed to make some changes